# how to match this word using regex (php)

Tags: php, regex

I have this keyword **3D DL1**

Right now i want to search for 3D DL1 keyword from user submitted data. The rule is as long as 3D and DL1 is present in the sentence, it is valid (case insensitive).

For example:

> BLASDHSDHD**3D**8qw9e08e2323**DL1** (valid)
>   BLASDHSDHD**3d**8qw9e08e2323**dL1** (valid)
>   3DDL1asdfjksldfjfdd (valid)
>   3Dzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz (invalid because no DL1)
>   zzzzzDL1 (invalid because no 3D)

How to do this using regex? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with two positive lookaheads...

```
$subject = 'BLASDHSDHD*3D*8qw9e08e2323*DL1*';

if(preg_match('/(?=.*3D)(?=.*DL1).*/i', $subject))
{
  echo 'pattern match';
}
else
{
  echo 'fail';
}
```

And without regex...

```
if(stripos($subject,'3D') !== FALSE AND stripos($subject,'DL1') !== FALSE)
```

Comment: Actualy, you could do this without regular expressions (see edit)

Comment: hi i found some problem. i open a new question for a better explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410739/how-to-detect-second-occurence-using-regex-php. thanks

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at this:

```
$regex = "@(3D(.*?)DL1)@";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is something like:

```
if(preg_match_all("/^((?:.*)3D(?:.*?)DL1(?:.*))$/i", $content, $_matches)) { 
}
```

Comment: I think this fails to match if the order of 3D/DL1 is reversed?