# How to detect second occurrence using regex? (php)

Tags: php, regex

From this question [How to match this using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395977/how-to-match-this-word-using-regex-php)

Right now i want to search for 3D D keyword from user submitted data. The rule is as long as 3D and D is present in the sentence, it is valid (case insensitive).

For example:

> 3Dzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz (invalid because no second occurence of D)
>   zzzzzD (invalid because no 3D)
>   xxx3DzzzzzD (valid because got 3D and D in string)

I am using this regex now but somehow it has one problem.

```
$subject = 'BLASHSH*3D*8qw9e08e2323*D*';

if(preg_match('/(?=.*3D)(?=.*D).*/i', $subject))
{
    echo 'pattern match';
}
else
{
    echo 'fail';
}
```

The problem is this string also will return true

> 3D (it should be invalid because no second occurrence of D)
>   3D ABC (it should be invalid because no second occurrence of D)

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `3DD`, `D3D`, and `cccDzzz3D` are all valid:

```
/(3D.*D)|(D.*3D)/i
```

And since you used the `i` modifier before I assume you want to accept `3d` and `d`? If not just remove the `i` from the end of the regex.

Comment: Sounds like the 3D must come before the second D.  If I understand correctly.

Comment: yes it is case insensitive. and also D can become before 3D. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the rule is that 3D must appear before D and can have any number of characters before, after, or in between (including zero characters), this should be sufficient:

```
/3D.*D/i
```